# passing argument to get_template_part() or a better way to code

Tags: custom-field, templates, post-meta, include, get-template-part

I have this include … `event-list.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop that displays upcoming events
 */
?>

<ul class="event-items">
<?php

    $yesterday = time() - 24*60*60;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'wr_event', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // show all posts 
        'meta_key' => 'event_date', 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => $yesterday,
        'meta_compare' => '>'           
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'item' );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

As you can see it's a custom query that compares a meta_key with the current date and only retrieves posts that are "newer" than yesterday.

however in my archives I want to do it the other way around.

On my index.php I have this

`<?php get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'list' ); ?>`

So this template above is getting executed and only retrieves events that are fresher than the last 24hours.

In my `archives.php` though I'd like to reverse the `meta_compare` value from ">" to "<" so I get the rest of the posts.

Is there a clever way of doing this?

So in my archives.php I have this as well …

`<?php get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'list' ); ?>`

Can I somehow pass the 'meta_compare' value to this template? So I can have and use the same template file in my index.php and in my archives.php but with different 'meta_compare' values.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a simple function with an argument to achieve that, the code is something like this:

```
function wpse63585_event_list( $fresh = true )
{
    echo '<ul class="event-items">';

    $yesterday = time() - 24*60*60;
    $compare = $fresh ? '>' : '<';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'wr_event',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // show all posts
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => $yesterday,
        'meta_compare' => $compare,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'item' );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

And then in your `index.php`, just call:

```
<?php wpse63585_event_list(); ?>
```

and in `archives.php`:

```
<?php wpse63585_event_list( false ); ?>
```

**Another solution** I can think about is you can register a global variable, like `$wpse63585_fresh = true`, and use that variable in your template part `event-list.php` to control the condition, like this:

In `index.php`:

```
global $wpse63585_fresh;

$wpse63585_fresh = true;
get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'list' );
```

In `archive.php`:

```
global $wpse63585_fresh;

$wpse63585_fresh = false;
get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'list' );
```

In `event-list.php`:

```
<ul class="event-items">
<?php
    global $wpse63585_fresh;
    $compare = $wpse63585_fresh ? '>' : '<';

    $yesterday = time() - 24*60*60;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'wr_event', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // show all posts 
        'meta_key' => 'event_date', 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => $yesterday,
        'meta_compare' => $compare           
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'item' );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, couldn't come up with this easy solution. I'll award you with the +50 as soon as it's possible. It says I have to wait for 22hours. Thank you again.

Comment: But still, there are many cases requiring variable passed to the get_template_part().